# LyX gives undefined control sequence in expl3 with mhchem

Tags: lyx, expl3, mhchem

I've recently started to use LyX with mhchem to typeset chemical formula, and everything works fine when using `pdflatex` from the command line, but for some reason LyX will throw an error about a bad control sequence in `expl3-code.tex`. Interestingly, it's still rendered fine if I press "Show Output Anyway".

I thought I might have had a bad MacTeX installation so I reinstalled it and I noticed that mhchem and LyX then behaved fine. **The issue only comes up after updating all packages to the latest version in TeX Live.** I assume it might be a backwards incompatible change in expl3.

mhchem: v4.08
l3kernal: Release 2019-09-05
LyX: 2.3.3 (I might have initially tried this with a git build, same thing)
pdflatex: 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)
macOS 10.14.6

Minimal erroring example (note that it renders fine, but still gives an error during compilation)

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{/Users/perry/Documents/}} % Inserted by LyX, necessary for the error
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
$\ce{Hi}$
\end{document}
```

```latex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mhchem/mhchem.sty
Package: mhchem 2018/06/22 v4.08 for typesetting chemical formulae
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2019-09-05 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2019-09-05 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count100
[...]
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count186
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \__kernel_file_name_quote:e 
                                       {\tl_to_str:n {/Users/perry/Documents...
l.27981   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

)
```

I'm new to TeXExchange™, so please let me know if I need to provide some more details.

Comment: Should be okay again after tomorrows update, see https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/624.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a missing `:e` variant of the `\__kernel_file_name_quote:n` function in the LaTeX3 kernel.

The same error is reported [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/624) and it was recently fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/eca1459100141435fc9cd073a1eb4cef2da07767). The updated code is already on CTAN, so if you update the `l3kernel` package the error should go away.

Comment: `\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_generate_variant:Nn\__kernel_file_name_quote:n{e}\ExplSyntaxOff` is *way* better

Comment: @egreg I completely agree. However the error happens while loading `expl3`, so it needs to be defined earlier...

Comment: I see: that's for the pesky `\input@path` before `\documentclass`. LyX… `:-(`

Comment: @egreg Yes :/ I think that loading `expl3` and defining the variant with your suggestion before the `\input@path` thingy would also work, but I don't know if LyX allows that. Anyhow, I'll remove the code once the update gets to CTAN so that people won't be tempted to use it ;-)